# Multiple Join - Propel

Tags: propel

I have a sort of map table that I need to perform multiple joins on to get other necessary data. How do you do that with Propel?

Sql would be something like:

SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.col1 = table2.id
INNER JOIN table3 on table1.col2 = table3.id

Comment: Also is there a way to sort of recursive join... join another table from a joined table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just read their instructions wrong.

To do this you just do:

```
$result = ClassQuery::create()->joinWith('ClassTable.Instructor')->joinWith('Instructor.Department');
```

Then you do:

```
$instructor = $result->getInstructor();
$department = $instructor->getDepartment();
```

Then you can access the properties through the getters:

```
$prop = $department->getName();
```

Comment: I think you can actually do that without using the joinWith.

Comment: You need the "joinWith" so can join the newly joined table with another table. Anotherwise Propel would try to just join always with the original table that created the query and this would fail.